# Вылетает программа на Python, если используется open()

Tags: python, консоль, visual-studio-code

Столкнулся с проблемой. Работаю в VS Code (в PyCharm'е не работает так, как я хочу + в нём лагает). Я пробовал использовать такой код:

```
text2 = open("Desktop\тест", "w+") 
text2 = write("test")
text2 = close()
```

А вот и не сработало. Код постоял секунду и вылетел. Файл не создался. Путь верный.

Comment: `with open("Desktop\тест", "w+") as text2: text2.write("test")`

Comment: Не-а. Всё равно вылетает.

Comment: Попробуй начать читать текст ошибок. Во второй и третьей строках написана полная ерунда.

Comment: with open("Desktop\тест", "w+") as text2: text2.write("test")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop\\тест' . Интересно то, что он написал \ два раза. Может, проблема в этом? Да и я юзал w+, то есть он ДОЛЖЕН был создать файлы если его нет, верно?

Comment: Так у вас относительный путь. И файл без расширения. Вы уверены, что когда ваш скрипт запускается, то у него текущий каталог именно тот, в котором есть подкаталог `Desktop` (это не обязательно тот же каталог, в котором лежит сам скрипт)? Вы уверены, что у вашего файла `тест` нет никакого расширения?

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке явно указано что нет такого файла. Да вы правы флаг `"w"` создаст файл в случае его отсутствия, однако это не касается директорий. Я полагаю вы работаете под виндовс, так же я полагаю вы пытаетесь создать файл на рабочем столе, и я уверяю вас что не существует такой директории как `Desktop`, только если вы не создали её ранее. Однако есть такой путь: `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\Desktop\`. Поэтому вам стоит использовать:

```
text2 = open(r"C:\Users\YOUR_USER\Desktop\тест", "w+") 
text2.write("test")
text2.close()
```

И касательно вашего вопроса про `"\\"`, это так называемое экранирование экранирования, потому что python воспринимает символ `\` как экранирование спец символов и по сути является таким же спец символом.

Comment: Спасибо, код перестал выдавать ту ошибку, но появилась Access Denied. Я копировал путь к папке, и вспомнил что у меня файлы на OneDrive хранятся. Мб тупой вопрос, но может нет доступа из за этого?

Comment: Я не могу судить об ошибке или её исправлении имея, собственно, только её название. Приведите полный стектрейс ошибки, код, который её вызывает, а в идеале создайте новый вопрос, в котором всё подробно распишите и, если вдруг моей компетенции не хватит другие участники сообщества так же постараются вам помочь. Но в первую очередь постарайтесь поискать в интернете, велика вероятность что кто-то уже сталкивался с нею раньше.